Problem in running ESP32-CAM video recording code
I wanted to upload the code in this link to my esp32-cam so that I can save the videos recorded by the camera to the sdcard. But I encountered the following error while uploading:
C:\Users\Hacker\Desktop\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-master\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod.ino:148:10: fatal error: soc/cpu.h: No such file or directory
  148 | #include "soc/cpu.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

exit status 1

Compilation error: soc/cpu.h: No such file or directory

Then I used the code in this link to solve the error. But I got another error again:
In file included from C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/freertos/FreeRTOS-Kernel/portable/xtensa/include/freertos/portmacro.h:79,
                 from C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/freertos/FreeRTOS-Kernel/include/freertos/portable.h:59,
                 from C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/freertos/FreeRTOS-Kernel/include/freertos/FreeRTOS.h:71,
                 from C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\3.0.3\cores\esp32/Arduino.h:33,
                 from C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino\sketches\6DF7905B3D01D6947831CF87E4541AFC\sketch\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod.ino.cpp:1:
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h: In function 'bool esp_dram_match_iram()':
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:30:13: error: 'SOC_DRAM_LOW' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'ESP_DRAM_LOGW'?
   30 |     return (SOC_DRAM_LOW == SOC_IRAM_LOW && SOC_DRAM_HIGH == SOC_IRAM_HIGH);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |             ESP_DRAM_LOGW
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:30:29: error: 'SOC_IRAM_LOW' was not declared in this scope
   30 |     return (SOC_DRAM_LOW == SOC_IRAM_LOW && SOC_DRAM_HIGH == SOC_IRAM_HIGH);
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:30:45: error: 'SOC_DRAM_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
   30 |     return (SOC_DRAM_LOW == SOC_IRAM_LOW && SOC_DRAM_HIGH == SOC_IRAM_HIGH);
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:30:62: error: 'SOC_IRAM_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
   30 |     return (SOC_DRAM_LOW == SOC_IRAM_LOW && SOC_DRAM_HIGH == SOC_IRAM_HIGH);
      |                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h: In function 'bool esp_ptr_in_iram(const void*)':
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:45:28: error: 'SOC_IRAM_LOW' was not declared in this scope
   45 |     return ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_IRAM_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_IRAM_HIGH);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:45:58: error: 'SOC_IRAM_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
   45 |     return ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_IRAM_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_IRAM_HIGH);
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h: In function 'bool esp_ptr_in_dram(const void*)':
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:58:28: error: 'SOC_DRAM_LOW' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'ESP_DRAM_LOGW'?
   58 |     return ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_DRAM_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_DRAM_HIGH);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            ESP_DRAM_LOGW
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:58:58: error: 'SOC_DRAM_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
   58 |     return ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_DRAM_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_DRAM_HIGH);
      |                                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h: In function 'bool esp_ptr_in_diram_dram(const void*)':
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:70:28: error: 'SOC_DIRAM_DRAM_LOW' was not declared in this scope
   70 |     return ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_DIRAM_DRAM_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_DIRAM_DRAM_HIGH);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:70:64: error: 'SOC_DIRAM_DRAM_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
   70 |     return ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_DIRAM_DRAM_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_DIRAM_DRAM_HIGH);
      |                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h: In function 'bool esp_ptr_in_rtc_iram_fast(const void*)':
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:100:28: error: 'SOC_RTC_IRAM_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  100 |     return ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_RTC_IRAM_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_RTC_IRAM_HIGH);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:100:62: error: 'SOC_RTC_IRAM_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
  100 |     return ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_RTC_IRAM_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_RTC_IRAM_HIGH);
      |                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h: In function 'bool esp_ptr_in_rtc_dram_fast(const void*)':
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:116:28: error: 'SOC_RTC_DRAM_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  116 |     return ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_RTC_DRAM_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_RTC_DRAM_HIGH);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:116:62: error: 'SOC_RTC_DRAM_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
  116 |     return ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_RTC_DRAM_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_RTC_DRAM_HIGH);
      |                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h: In function 'bool esp_ptr_in_rtc_slow(const void*)':
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:132:28: error: 'SOC_RTC_DATA_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  132 |     return ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_RTC_DATA_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_RTC_DATA_HIGH);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:132:62: error: 'SOC_RTC_DATA_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
  132 |     return ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_RTC_DATA_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_RTC_DATA_HIGH);
      |                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h: In function 'void* esp_ptr_diram_dram_to_iram(const void*)':
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:149:23: error: 'SOC_DIRAM_IRAM_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  149 |     return (void *) ( SOC_DIRAM_IRAM_LOW + ((intptr_t)p - SOC_DIRAM_DRAM_LOW) );
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:149:59: error: 'SOC_DIRAM_DRAM_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  149 |     return (void *) ( SOC_DIRAM_IRAM_LOW + ((intptr_t)p - SOC_DIRAM_DRAM_LOW) );
      |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h: In function 'void* esp_ptr_diram_iram_to_dram(const void*)':
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:163:23: error: 'SOC_DIRAM_DRAM_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  163 |     return (void *) ( SOC_DIRAM_DRAM_LOW + ((intptr_t)p - SOC_DIRAM_IRAM_LOW) );
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:163:59: error: 'SOC_DIRAM_IRAM_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  163 |     return (void *) ( SOC_DIRAM_DRAM_LOW + ((intptr_t)p - SOC_DIRAM_IRAM_LOW) );
      |                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h: In function 'bool esp_ptr_dma_capable(const void*)':
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:180:27: error: 'SOC_DMA_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  180 |     return (intptr_t)p >= SOC_DMA_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_DMA_HIGH;
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:180:56: error: 'SOC_DMA_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
  180 |     return (intptr_t)p >= SOC_DMA_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_DMA_HIGH;
      |                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h: In function 'bool esp_ptr_executable(const void*)':
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:216:19: error: 'SOC_IROM_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  216 |     return (ip >= SOC_IROM_LOW && ip < SOC_IROM_HIGH)
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:216:40: error: 'SOC_IROM_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
  216 |     return (ip >= SOC_IROM_LOW && ip < SOC_IROM_HIGH)
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:217:19: error: 'SOC_IRAM_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  217 |         || (ip >= SOC_IRAM_LOW && ip < SOC_IRAM_HIGH)
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:217:40: error: 'SOC_IRAM_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
  217 |         || (ip >= SOC_IRAM_LOW && ip < SOC_IRAM_HIGH)
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:218:19: error: 'SOC_IROM_MASK_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  218 |         || (ip >= SOC_IROM_MASK_LOW && ip < SOC_IROM_MASK_HIGH)
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:218:45: error: 'SOC_IROM_MASK_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
  218 |         || (ip >= SOC_IROM_MASK_LOW && ip < SOC_IROM_MASK_HIGH)
      |                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:223:19: error: 'SOC_RTC_IRAM_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  223 |         || (ip >= SOC_RTC_IRAM_LOW && ip < SOC_RTC_IRAM_HIGH)
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:223:44: error: 'SOC_RTC_IRAM_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
  223 |         || (ip >= SOC_RTC_IRAM_LOW && ip < SOC_RTC_IRAM_HIGH)
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h: In function 'bool esp_ptr_internal(const void*)':
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:247:25: error: 'SOC_MEM_INTERNAL_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  247 |     r = ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_MEM_INTERNAL_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_MEM_INTERNAL_HIGH);
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:247:63: error: 'SOC_MEM_INTERNAL_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
  247 |     r = ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_MEM_INTERNAL_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_MEM_INTERNAL_HIGH);
      |                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:250:26: error: 'SOC_RTC_DATA_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  250 |     r |= ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_RTC_DATA_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_RTC_DATA_HIGH);
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:250:60: error: 'SOC_RTC_DATA_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
  250 |     r |= ((intptr_t)p >= SOC_RTC_DATA_LOW && (intptr_t)p < SOC_RTC_DATA_HIGH);
      |                                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h: In function 'bool esp_ptr_in_drom(const void*)':
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:291:31: error: 'SOC_DROM_LOW' was not declared in this scope
  291 |     int32_t drom_start_addr = SOC_DROM_LOW;
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:301:61: error: 'SOC_DROM_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
  301 |     return ((intptr_t)p >= drom_start_addr && (intptr_t)p < SOC_DROM_HIGH);
      |                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h: In function 'bool esp_stack_ptr_in_dram(uint32_t)':
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:315:19: error: 'SOC_DRAM_LOW' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'ESP_DRAM_LOGW'?
  315 |     return !(sp < SOC_DRAM_LOW + 0x10 || sp > SOC_DRAM_HIGH - 0x10 || ((sp & 0xF) != 0));
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   ESP_DRAM_LOGW
C:\Users\Hacker\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\tools\esp32-arduino-libs\idf-release_v5.1-dc859c1e67\esp32/include/esp_hw_support/include/esp_memory_utils.h:315:47: error: 'SOC_DRAM_HIGH' was not declared in this scope
  315 |     return !(sp < SOC_DRAM_LOW + 0x10 || sp > SOC_DRAM_HIGH - 0x10 || ((sp & 0xF) != 0));
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\Hacker\Desktop\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-master\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod.ino: In lambda function:
C:\Users\Hacker\Desktop\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-master\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod.ino:1304:96: error: 'union arduino_event_info_t' has no member named 'disconnected'; did you mean 'eth_connected'?
 1304 |       Serial.printf( "\nframe_cnt: %8d, WiFi event Reason: %d , Status: %d\n", frame_cnt, info.disconnected.reason, WiFi.status());
      |                                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                                                eth_connected
C:\Users\Hacker\Desktop\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-master\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod.ino:1305:96: error: 'union arduino_event_info_t' has no member named 'disconnected'; did you mean 'eth_connected'?
 1305 |       logfile.printf("\nframe_cnt: %8d, WiFi event Reason: %d , Status: %d\n", frame_cnt, info.disconnected.reason, WiFi.status());
      |                                                                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                                                eth_connected
C:\Users\Hacker\Desktop\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-master\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod.ino: In lambda function:
C:\Users\Hacker\Desktop\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-master\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod.ino:1327:98: error: 'union arduino_event_info_t' has no member named 'disconnected'; did you mean 'eth_connected'?
 1327 |         Serial.printf( "\nframe_cnt: %8d, WiFi event Reason: %d , Status: %d\n", frame_cnt, info.disconnected.reason, WiFi.status());
      |                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                                                  eth_connected
C:\Users\Hacker\Desktop\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-master\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod\ESP32-CAM-Video-Recorder-junior-50x-lpmod.ino:1328:98: error: 'union arduino_event_info_t' has no member named 'disconnected'; did you mean 'eth_connected'?
 1328 |         logfile.printf("\nframe_cnt: %8d, WiFi event Reason: %d , Status: %d\n", frame_cnt, info.disconnected.reason, WiFi.status());
      |                                                                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                                                                  eth_connected

exit status 1

Compilation error: 'union arduino_event_info_t' has no member named 'disconnected'; did you mean 'eth_connected'?

How do I solve the problem????
I asked AI to solve this problem but no answers.
Help!!!!!!!

Are you for sure you set the "AI Tinker" board for upload (and not the "usual" ESP32 Dev. Board) ?

yesss. I'm sure

AI Thinker ESP32-CAM
